# Best tools to download all the html files from a website, and to re-upload them

Tags: html, ftp

I need to add two lines of html to every page on a large website.  I will be using a regex to do it.

I would like to know the best tools to download all the html files from a website, then ftp upload them back up on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any standard FTP program and limit transfer to files with a `.html` extension. Then mirror the files back up.

Or you could just download everything via FTP, make changes to only the `.html` extensioned files, and then upload modified files back up (should be only `.html`) files.

I find [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) a very decent cross platform FTP client.

Comment: I had trouble finding a good ftp client to do filter the downloads.  Then I found FileZilla which is working nicely.

Comment: I probably should have put a link to FileZilla in my answer, I find it's a very decent cross platform FTP client.